# Performance cost of HBase table with a high number of versions per row?

Tags: java, hbase

We are implementing a HBase storage mechanism which will have one table that will make use of a (String) row key and (long) timestamp to maintain multiple versions of a single row. This is a core feature of HBase, and will be very useful for us.

In most cases, the rows will only have a dozen or so versions, and each version should only be a few KB in size across all cells. However, there is an edge case in which a row could have *hundreds* of versions, each with a different timestamp, and its unclear if there would be any performance or scaling cost to setting the max number of versions per row (just on this one table) to "1000" (one thousand).

In terms of access patterns, when we pull data out it will be one of:

1. Pull out the "latest" version of the row, given a row key
2. Pull out a specified version of the row, given a row key and timestamp
3. Pull out a single cell (called "ts") containing a long from each
   version of the row, given a row key

The last, in 3) is to allow us to discover what versions exist for each row without having to pull out all versions of a row. Worst case scenario; we would end up getting back 1000 (one thousand) long's in a HBase Get request. That would be 64 Kb. We will never have a need to request every single cell on every single version of a row in one Get request.

There has been a suggestion internal to the team that this could cause performance issues, however, we can't find clarification either way in the HBase manual.

So, given the above, my question is - Is there any kind of performance cost to us having a table with (potentially) 1000 versions per row?

Comment: Hi, actually I had the same question as you. Did you figure out the solution for your questions? The maximum number of version of my data model is around 100. So wondering if you had any serious problem implementing that idea.

Comment: Hi @notilas the accepted answer pointed out that it *was* in the HBase manual, albeit a bit vague. We set the max versions we have to 50, and have simply accepted that our edge case with hundreds of versions will have to be dealt with some other way. We have not had any performance issues with 50, but we recently did some analysis on our ingest data and discovered that less than 1% of our current data had more than 1 version. The extreme edge case of hundreds of versions, we have not encountered yet, and we don't yet really have a solution for. So can't help there. Hope that was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A {row, column, version} tuple exactly specifies a cell in HBase. It’s
>   possible to have an unbounded number of cells where the row and column
>   are the same but the cell address differs only in its version
>   dimension.
>
> While rows and column keys are expressed as bytes, the version is
>   specified using a long integer. ..... [links](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/book.html)

As  you see HBase is designed to have a maximum version of Integer.MAX_VALUE, but if you insert a version close to that number, there may be a lot of risk waiting for you.

> 37. Number of Versions
>       37.1. Maximum Number of Versions The maximum number of row versions to store is configured per column family via HColumnDescriptor. The
>       default for max versions is 1. This is an important parameter because
>       as described in Data Model section HBase does not overwrite row
>       values, but rather stores different values per row by time (and
>       qualifier). Excess versions are removed during major compactions. The
>       number of max versions may need to be increased or decreased depending
>       on application needs.
>
> **It is not recommended setting the number of max versions to an
>   exceedingly high level** (e.g., hundreds or more) unless those old
>   values are very dear to you because this will greatly **increase
>   StoreFile size.**

From the official document We can get some information  about  your question

First of all it  is likely to be out of memory  when compact .

Secondly  the region of a single rowkey will not be splited .

Comment: Perfect. That's what we were looking for but couldn't find. Many thanks.